# Converting CSV to JSON and putting JSON into html table with JS

Tags: javascript, html, json, csv

I have the following problem:

i need to fill an HTML table with some data out of a CSV file for a university project, we are only allowed to use vanilla JavaScript. I have been trying this for the last three days, looking at code used to parse CSV to JSON and then build a table out of it. The code i have written looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
            url: 'world_data_v1.csv',
            dataType: 'text',
        }).done(csvToJSON);

        function csvToJSON(data){
            var table_lines = data.split("\n");
            var results = [];
            var headers = table_lines[0].split(",");

            for(var x=1; x<table_lines.length; x++){
                var content = {};
                var current_line = tabel_lines[x].split(",");
                for(var y=1; y<headers.length; y++){
                    content[headers[y]] = current_line[y];
                }
                results.push(content);
            }
            return results;
        }
        function buildHtmlTable() {
            var data = results;
            var table = document.createElement("table");
            table.border = "1";

            var tableLength = data[0].length;
            var row = table.insertRow(-1);
            for (var i = 0; i<tableLenght; i++) {
                var header = document.createElement("th");
                header.innerHTML = data[0][i];
                row.appendChild(header);
            }
            
            for (var i; i<results.length; i++){
                row = table.insertRow(-1);
                for (var x=0; x<tableLength; x++){
                    var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                    cell.innerHTML = data[i][x];
                }
            }
        }
        var table = document.getElementById("Table");
        table.innerHTML ="";
        table.appendChild(table);
    </script>
```

The CSV i am trying to parse looks like this:

```
id ,name ,birth rate per 1000,cell phones per 100,children per woman,electricity consumption per capita,gdp_per_capita,gdp_per_capita_growth,inflation annual,internet user per 100,life expectancy,military expenditure percent of gdp,gps_lat      ,gps_long 001,Brazil ,16.405 ,90.01936334 ,1.862  ,2201.808724                       ,4424.758692   ,-1.520402823 ,8.228535058  ,39.22 ,74             ,1.615173655 ,-14.235004000,-51.925280000002,Canada  ,10.625             ,70.70997244  ,1.668  ,15119.76414 ,25069.86915   ,-3.953353186         ,2.944408564     ,80.17086651 ,80.9 ,1.415710422                        ,56.130366000 ,-106.346771000003,Chile ,15.04  ,97.01862561        ,1.873 ,3276.06449  ,6451.631126  ,-2.610485847 ,7.47050527  ,38.8  ,78.8 ,3.064076139 ,-35.675147000,71.542969000
```

It is currently not working, and as a JS newbie I am stuck.

**Edit**: I have noticed that I used some jQuery code, which is obviously not vanilla JS. I will work out a way to load the csv without jQuery.

Comment: What do you mean with "currently not working"? Is there any error message? How does the json look like?

Comment: @JuleWolf i made a rookie misstake in the buildHtmlTable function, as it takes no parameters, so it can't build a table as it doesn't have any data to build one out off. Currently fixing it.

Comment: is it required that you convert it to json first? you can directly use csv to generate the table

Comment: They recommended us to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to load CSV data from a file, instead of using an AJAX call. If you require to do an AJAX call, take a look into [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), this is pure JS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Load CSV file</h1>

  <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile" onchange="readfile()">
  <table id="_table">
</table>
<script>
function appendJsonToTable(jsonArray){
    const headersHtml = Object.keys(jsonArray[0]).map(h => `<th>${h}</th>`).join('')
    const tableHtml = jsonArray.map(row => {
        const columns = Object.values(row);
        const columnsInTable = columns.map(c => `<td>${c}</td>`).join('')
        return `<tr>${columnsInTable}</tr>`;
    }).join('')
    const table = document.getElementById("_table");
    console.log('tableHtml:', tableHtml);
    table.innerHTML = [headersHtml, tableHtml].join('');
}
function csvToJSON(csvDataString){
    const rowsHeader = csvDataString.split('\r').join('').split('\n')
    const headers = rowsHeader[0].split(',');
    const content = rowsHeader.filter((_,i) => i>0);
    console.log('Headers: ',headers);
    const jsonFormatted = content.map(row => {
        const columns = row.split(',');
        return columns.reduce((p,c, i) => {
            p[headers[i]] = c;
            return p;
        }, {})
    })
    console.log('jsonFormatted:',jsonFormatted);
    // here you have the JSON formatted
    return jsonFormatted;
}
function readfile(e){
    var file = document.getElementById("myfile").files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener('load', e => {
        const csvData = e.target.result.toString();
        console.log('CSV Data:', csvData);
        appendJsonToTable(csvToJSON(csvData))
    })
    reader.readAsText(file, 'UTF-8')
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

For the purpose of using data into an HTML Table, deconstructing a CSV into a nested array is way more compatible with table, as it's in fact a table data format.

However, you can use the methods above to build an HTML Table using string literals instead of DOM manipulation, which has more control for static DOM and is very useful for BE rendering of static on plain JS.